# [solved]get Product ID and URL from Product page as PHP variable

Tags: product, product-attribute, url, magento-1, product-view

On the product page, I want to read the Product URL (http://www.example.com/myCategory/myProduct.html) and put it as string in a PHP variable like `$myProductURL`. I also want do to this with the ID of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current url of any page like this:

```
$url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

and you can get the product id in a product page like this:

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
if ($product) {
    $id = $product->getId();
}
else {
    //it means you are not in a product page
    $id = null;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I tryed the getCurrentUrl but then I see an error massage on my product page: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Helper_Data::getCurrentUrl()"

Comment: @TISA-Optimierung.de. What Magento version are you using?

Comment: @TISA-Optimierung.de. Never mind. I got something wrong. It should be `Mage::helper('core/url')` instead of `Mage::helper('core')`. I fixed it.

Comment: THANKS again. this worked! i´m using magento v1.9 but now i´m happy thanks to your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can `not get Product url from this url`
if you want to get product id then use `Registry variable which give  u product id`

```
if (Mage::registry('current_product')) {
    $Productid = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
}
```

**But note that it is only working when you are in product page**

Comment: this worked well. thank you. i only need the id on the product page. now i look for the same solution with the product URL

Comment: see at http://makandracards.com/magento/8371-getting-a-products-url